# How can I increment many fields at once when data structure matches Model exactly in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I currently have a schema with many fields, all of type number like this:

```
const mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fields: {
        field1: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        },
        field2: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        },
        ...
        field20: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        }
    }
});

const MyModel = mongoose.model('model', mySchema);
module.exports = MyModel;
```

I currently increment all the fields individually:

```
const fields = {
    field1: 5,
    field2: 10,
    ...
    field20: 7
};

MyModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    {...},
    {
        $inc: {
            "fields.field1": fields.field1,
            "fields.field2": fields.field2,
            ...
            "fields.field20": fields.field20
        }
    }
);
```

Is there a shorthand way to increment all these fields at once?
Something like below:

```
MyModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    {...},
    {
        $inc: {
            "fields": fields
        }
    }
);
```

This understandably gives the error

> "Cannot increment with non-numeric argument: ..."

Comment: How to possible who wants  that because $inc have one key name and another number value

Comment: Is there a possibility to change the schema of your collection?

Comment: I can change the schema, but what are you suggesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not supported by mongodb
ref: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/

However, it is possible to write a helper function that produces these mappings.

```
function generateIncrement(fields){
    return Object.keys(fields).reduce((mappings, key) => {
        mappings[`fields.${key}`] = fields[key]
        return mappings
    },{})
}
```

This would give

```
const fields = {
    field1: 5,
    field2: 10,
    ...
    field20: 7
};

MyModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    {...},
    {
        $inc: generateIncrement(fields)
    }
);
```

It could be also isolated in the model

The model would be

```
const mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fields: {
        field1: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        },
        field2: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        },
        ...
        field20: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        }
    }
});
MyModel.static({
    incrementAllFields: async function incrementAllFields(query, fields) {
        return this.findOneAndUpdate(
            query,
            {
                $inc: generateIncrement(fields)
            }
        );
    }
})
const MyModel = mongoose.model('model', mySchema);
module.exports = MyModel;
```

The usage would become

```
const fields = {
    field1: 5,
    field2: 10,
    ...
    field20: 7
};

MyModel.incrementAllFields({...}, fields)
```

Finally, it is also possible to make the helper function more generic to specify the "root" key or support deep path safe searching

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the schema.
Try this:

**01)** Change the schema like the document sample:

```
{
    "fields" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "field1",
            "value" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "field2",
            "value" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "field3",
            "value" : 3
        }
    ]
}
```

**02)** Update Command in MongoDB(Only for reference):

```
db.collectionName.update(
    {},
    { "$inc": { "fields.$[].value": 1 } }
)
```

**03)** Possible implementation:

```
MyModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    {...},
    {
        $inc: {
            "fields.$[].value": 1
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Will this increment all the fields by the same value?